# Create a NZPLSQL to find min(date) and a max(date) for a group of fields that serve as a key

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, netezza

I would like to know how I can execute a select from a procedure stored in `Netezza`.

I currently have the procedure under construction and I read that the raise notice serves to print on screen, however I do not know how (or if you can print a table in sql) just as if you were doing a query in traditional sql.

What the query is trying to do is that for a record,

```
COUNT (*) AS N_REPETITIONS, 
CDS.CASO_PACIENTE_FK, 
CDS.RESIVALITY_SPECIALITY_COD, 
CDS.CASO_NIVEL_ATENCION_TIPO, 
CDS.CASO_TIPO_PRESTACION_FK, 
CDS.DIVING_DATE_DAY, 
CDS.SALID_DATE_DAY
```

and that it gives me `MIN(CDS.DERIVACION_FECHA_HORA)` and `MAX(CDS.SALIDA_FECHA_HORA)` based on a key that are the fields.

If I have dates between `MIN(CDS.DERIVACION_FECHA_HORA)` and `MAX(CDS.SALIDA_FECHA_HORA)` for a `CDS.CASO_PACIENTE_FK`, i want that register added to number of register for each `CDS.CASO_PACIENTE_FK`

Here the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_ANALISIS_DUPLICADOS()
RETURNS REFTABLE(NETEZZA_PROD_LISTA_ESPERA_NOGES.LLAVE_CASOS_DUPLICADOS)
EXECUTE AS OWNER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS

BEGIN_PROC

  DECLARE

  num_args INTEGER;
```

I am just starting to work with `Netezza`.

Thank you in advance to whom you answer.

---

This is the code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_ANALISIS_DUPLICADOS()
    RETURNS REFTABLE(NETEZZA_PROD_LISTA_ESPERA_NOGES.LLAVE_CASOS_DUPLICADOS)
    EXECUTE AS OWNER 
    LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS

    BEGIN_PROC

  DECLARE

  num_args INTEGER;
  typ oid;
  idx INTEGER;
  N_REPETICIONES NUMERIC(19);
  CASO_PACIENTE_FK NUMERIC(19);
  DERIVACION_ESPECIALIDAD_COD VARCHAR(255);
  CASO_NIVEL_ATENCION_TIPO NUMERIC(19);
  CASO_TIPO_PRESTACION_FK NUMERIC(19);
  DERIVACION_FECHA_HORA TIMESTAMP;
  SALIDA_FECHA_HORA TIMESTAMP;

  --CURSOR FECHA_HORA_DERIVACION_MIN;
  --CURSOR FECHA_HORA_SALIDA_MAX;
  CURSOR CASO_PACIENTE_FK;
  CURSOR DERIVACION_ESPECIALIDAD_COD;
  CURSOR CASO_NIVEL_ATENCION_TIPO;
  CURSOR CASO_TIPO_PRESTACION_FK;
  --L_CONDITIONS VARCHAR(1000);

--Duplicados CNE MIN

BEGIN

num_args := PROC_ARGUMENT_TYPES.count;

FOR CASO_PACIENTE_FK IN
    num_args := CASO_PACIENTE_FK.count;
--RAISE NOTICE ’Number of arguments: %’, num_args;
    for i IN 0
        CASO_PACIENTE_FK.count - 1 LOOP
        typ := CASO_PACIENTE_FK(i);
        idx := i+1;

FOR DERIVACION_ESPECIALIDAD_COD IN
    num_args := DERIVACION_ESPECIALIDAD_COD.count;
    for j IN 0
        DERIVACION_ESPECIALIDAD_COD.count - 1 LOOP
        typ := DERIVACION_ESPECIALIDAD_COD(j);
        idx := j+1;

FOR CASO_NIVEL_ATENCION_TIPO IN
    num_args := CASO_PACIENTE_FK.count;
--RAISE NOTICE ’Number of arguments: %’, num_args;
    for k IN 0
        CASO_NIVEL_ATENCION_TIPO.count - 1 LOOP
        typ := CASO_NIVEL_ATENCION_TIPO(k);
        idx := k+1;

FOR CASO_TIPO_PRESTACION_FK IN
    num_args := CASO_TIPO_PRESTACION_FK.count;
--RAISE NOTICE ’Number of arguments: %’, num_args;
    for a IN 0
        CASO_TIPO_PRESTACION_FK.count - 1 LOOP
        typ := CASO_TIPO_PRESTACION_FK(a);
        idx := a+1;

--RAISE NOTICE ’argument $% is type % and has the value ’’%’’’,
--idx, typ, $idx;
   F FLAG = 1 THEN
     IF Fecha_Entrada = SELECT COUNT(*) AS N_REPETICIONES, MIN(CDS.DERIVACION_FECHA_HORA) AS FECHA_HORA_DERIVACION_MIN
        FROM NETEZZA_PROD_SIGTE_DIARIO.SIG_CASO_DERIVACION_SALIDA CDS
        WHERE (CDS.CASO_TIPO_PRESTACION_FK=1
        OR CDS.CASO_TIPO_PRESTACION_FK=2)
        --AND CDS.DERIVACION_FECHA_HORA >= CDS.DERIVACION_FECHA_HORA
        GROUP BY CDS.CASO_PACIENTE_FK, CDS.DERIVACION_ESPECIALIDAD_COD, /*CDS.DERIVACION_ESTABLECIMIENTO_COD*/
        CDS.CASO_NIVEL_ATENCION_TIPO, /*CDS.DERIVACION_FECHA_HORA,*/ CDS.CASO_TIPO_PRESTACION_FK, CDS.DERIVACION_FECHA_HORA,
        CDS.SALIDA_FECHA_HORA
        HAVING COUNT(*)>1
        ORDER BY N_REPETICIONES, CDS.CASO_PACIENTE_FK, CDS.DERIVACION_FECHA_HORA, CDS.SALIDA_FECHA_HORA DESC
     THEN Fecha_Entrada = 'TRUE';
     ELSE FLAG = 0 THEN
     Fecha_Entrada = 'FALSE'

   F FLAG = 1 THEN
     IF Fecha_Salida = SELECT COUNT(*) AS N_REPETICIONES, MAX(CDS.SALIDA_FECHA_HORA) AS FECHA_HORA_DERIVACION_MIN
        FROM NETEZZA_PROD_SIGTE_DIARIO.SIG_CASO_DERIVACION_SALIDA CDS
        WHERE (CDS.CASO_TIPO_PRESTACION_FK=1
        OR CDS.CASO_TIPO_PRESTACION_FK=2)
        --AND CDS.DERIVACION_FECHA_HORA >= CDS.DERIVACION_FECHA_HORA
        GROUP BY CDS.CASO_PACIENTE_FK, CDS.DERIVACION_ESPECIALIDAD_COD, /*CDS.DERIVACION_ESTABLECIMIENTO_COD*/
        CDS.CASO_NIVEL_ATENCION_TIPO, /*CDS.DERIVACION_FECHA_HORA,*/ CDS.CASO_TIPO_PRESTACION_FK, CDS.DERIVACION_FECHA_HORA,
        CDS.SALIDA_FECHA_HORA
        HAVING COUNT(*)>1
        ORDER BY N_REPETICIONES, CDS.CASO_PACIENTE_FK, CDS.DERIVACION_FECHA_HORA, CDS.SALIDA_FECHA_HORA DESC
     THEN Fecha_Salida = 'TRUE';
     ELSE FLAG = 0 THEN
     Fecha_Salida = 'FALSE'

END LOOP;

END LOOP;

END LOOP;

END LOOP;

RETURN REFTABLE;

RAISE NOTICE 'Hello, %', MYNAME;  --Right Here must go the Println (Select field1, field2, etc.....)

--END;
--COMMIT;
END;
END_PROC;
```

Comment: This doesn't look like an Oracle question.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - Netezza has a procedural language which is very similar to Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: @gonzalo - you'll probably get more helpful answers if you posted a simpler piece of code which focuses on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: To expand on what @APC said, see [ask] and [mcve].